# Bridge edge loop not working for two mesh cube

Tags: edges

when i select the edge and bridge edge loop, the upper body parts and lower body parts is not connecting. What should i do?
[image]

Comment: for bridge edge loops to work, it has to be one object. So select both in object mode, press ctrl-J and try again.

Comment: ohh it worked, thankyou so much!